# Unable to acquire priority service for UK GAE (work) type visa

Tags: visas, uk

I'm in a bit of a pickle. The start of my internship in the UK is coming close, and I still haven't applied for my visa. I'm applying from Portugal and would like to pay for the priority service, which [should be available for my case](https://pos.tlscontact.com/visa-processing-priority), according to the TLSContact office.

However, when I'm prompted to select the type of service in UKVI's website, only the standard option is available:

[image]

If anyone has followed the same immigration route, should I maybe select "standard service" here, and later pay for the priority service?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The info in the link says “Where available, Priority and Super Priority Visas will be displayed when you book your appointment.“ For Portugal that means appointments in Lisbon. Paying for the Priority service doesn’t guarantee a quick answer BTW

Comment: @Traveller this service should be available in Portugal, according to: https://pos.tlscontact.com/tls-service-options#mup-ftu. I don't have an appointment yet though, so I'm not sure of how they would know if I'm eligible for the priority service or not? This is why I asked if maybe I would be able to upgrade later... Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: They know by the type of visa being applied for

Comment: I am also applying for a similar visa. Did you manage to book a priority or super priority option after this point in the visa application? Thanks :)

Comment: For me, priority option was available in the VFS website.

Comment: @GraceHoward I was indeed! On TLSContact's website when booking my appointment 